# Need to model properties on relations in UML. How is this done?

Tags: uml

I have a datastructure that involves rating items, much like Netflix do. Now those ratings are numbers that are attached to relations between objects in a graph database. However, it seems as if attaching properties to relations, not nodes, in UML seems to be a difficult thing to find to do.

To elucidate. Object A rates Object B with a score of 8. So there are two objects that are connected by a relation called "rating" which has a value of 8 on it. Now, I would rather not create a relation for each value (A and B are related by rating score 8) -- this seems like a bad way of doing things. If someone could point me to how to represent this that would be brilliant.

Thanks

Comment: You might consider an Association Class, which is both an association with end points, and a class so it can have members.

Comment: @ErikEidt, you should add a bit more details and make it an answer. I don't want to take your credits so I will wait for you to do so rather than answering myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an association class.
Consider it as a class „C“ that

- links between A and B
- has properties, such as the Rating score

You could implement it, for example, by referencing from C to both A and B (and vice versa),

Find some more info for example [here](http://etutorials.org/Programming/UML/Chapter+6.+Class+Diagrams+Advanced+Concepts/Association+Class/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443724/uml-how-to-implement-association-class-in-java).